# Lenovo L440 won't boot into Debian installation CD or Debian-installed HDD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, debian, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo L440 and a Lenovo X61. I want to install Debian Wheezy on thee L440. This morning, the L440 could successfully boot into Windows 8 from it's hard drive.

I created an installation of Wheezy on a USB flash drive with Unetbootin. I created an installation CD of Wheezy with Unetbootin. The X61 can successfully boot into the flash drive. The X61 does not have a CD drive.

I have attempted to boot from the live CD and the flash drive from the L440's boot menu. In both cases, the screen fades to black, and then returns me to the boot menu with no error message.

I removed the L440's hard drive, and installed it in the X61. I then successfully installed Wheezy onto the hard drive from the flash drive. I'm able to boot into the Wheezy hard drive on the L440. After replacing the hard drive into the L440. I booted from the hard drive from the boot menu. Once again, the screen fades to black, and then returns me to the boot menu with no error message.

What's the deal?

Comment: is the L440 UEFI based? does it use secureboot? You may need to turn that off to install linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Debian Web site](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/debian-installer/) explicitly acknowledges occasional problems with booting on amd64 machines:

> Potential issues with UEFI booting on amd64
>
> There have been some reports of issues booting the Debian Installer in UEFI mode on amd64 systems. Some systems apparently do not boot reliably using grub-efi, and some others show graphics corruption problems when displaying the initial installation splash screen.
> If you encounter either of these issues, please file a bug report and give as much detail as possible, both about the symptoms and your hardware - this should assist the team to fix these bugs. As a workaround for now, try switching off UEFI and installing using Legacy BIOS or Fallback mode instead.

The X61 is an older model, so I am pretty sure it boots in BIOS mode (what is now called legacy-BIOS mode, when UEFI boot is also present). Also, I bet it is a 32bit machine, again judging from its age, for which the Debian page reports no issues even in the presence of UEFI boot.

Thus your best bet, on the L440, it to turn *Secure Boot* off, to enable *BIOS legacy mode* which of course means disabling UEFI boot, and trying it like that.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I've learned my lesson for future problems: Check the developer's release notes and errata notes.